# Customizing output file name

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-staticfiles, pypdf

```
with open('media_cdn/account/pdf01.pdf', 'wb') as out_file:
        output.write(out_file)
```

How can I format this to have a custom name for each output? For example, I have tried:

```
author_id=str(instance.author.id)

with open('media_cdn/account/{author_id}-pdf01.pdf', 'wb') as out_file:
    output.write(out_file)
```

however, the file is output as `"{author_id}-pdf01.pdf"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
with open("media_cdn/account/{0}-pdf01.pdf".format(author_id), 'wb') as out_file:
```

in place of

```
with open('media_cdn/account/{author_id}-pdf01.pdf', 'wb') as out_file:
```

`'media_cdn/account/{author_id}-pdf01.pdf'` is a string. `{author_id}` part of this string will NOT be substituted by `author_id` variable by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just do this

```
author_id=str(instance.author.id)

with open(f'media_cdn/account/{author_id}-pdf01.pdf', 'wb') as out_file:
    output.write(out_file)
```